# Should I assign or reset a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Given the common situation where the lifespan of an owned object is linked to its owner, I can use a unique pointer one of 2 ways . .

**It can be assigned:**

```
class owner
{
    std::unique_ptr<someObject> owned;    
public:
    owner()
    {
        owned=std::unique_ptr<someObject>(new someObject());        
    }
};
```

**The reset method can be utilised:**

```
class owner
{
    std::unique_ptr<someObject> owned;    
public:
    owner()
    {
        owned.reset(new someObject());
    }
};
```

In the interests of best practice, should I prefer one form over the other?

**EDIT:** Sorry folks. I over simplified this. The heap allocation occurs in an initialise method and not in the ctor. Therefore, I cannot use initialiser lists.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From [the docs of `unique_ptr`'s `operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D):

> Transfers ownership of the object pointed to by r to *this as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment from `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`.

And all you need of that is the `reset` call, so it's simpler to just call it directly

Comment: I know it's late, but just for future readers. According to Scott Meyers in his book Effective Modern C++, std::make_unique<T> is preferable, because it offers exception safety: owner = std::make_unique<someObject>(). The problem is that std::make_unique<T> is part of C++14 (not C++11), but here you can find [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt) a good implementation that you can copy-paste.

Comment: @FrancisMoy Possible to point out the exception safety case?

Comment: The question of exception safety does not apply here. Exception safety is relevant when passing multiple arguments to a function, which is safer if each one is created with make_unique.

Answer (score 19):

The proper way to do this (that you didn't list) is to use the constructor of `owned`:

```
owner() : owned(new someObject())
{}
```

Apart from that I'd prefer `reset` as you don't create a useless intermediate instance in that case (even though there might be no difference on the machine level as the optimizer can do a lot there).

Comment: "I'd prefer reset as you don't create a useless intermediate instance" - that gets it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**: Both solutions are equivalent. Which to choose is a matter of style or what you want to express.

**In Detail**: The best and most preferable solution is to use a different design: try to avoid any lifecycle state. This can be achieved by *initialising* the `unique_ptr` immediately with the newly heap allocated instance:

```
class owner
{
    std::unique_ptr<someObject> owned;    
public:
    owner()
        : owned{new someObject()}
        { }
};
```

Why is this preferable? because it either succeeds or fails as a whole. If the allocation fails or if the ctor of `someObject` blows up, the construction of `owner` also throws. This implies: you can get an `owner` instance only in complete, valid state. As an added bonus, there is no intermediary involved.

However — there are cases when you *can not create at initialisation.* This is especially the case when your use case *explicitly calls for lifecycle state:* There may be a situation where you need the `owned` to be empty sometimes, and only place the `someObject` later into it, triggered by external events.

In such a situation the question arises if we should assign from `make_unique` or if we should `reset()`. Both are equivalent in terms of functionality. Both will safely clean-up another `someObject` instance which happens to sit in the `unique_ptr`. Both will transfer ownership and move the deleter alongside.

- using `reset()` implies the meaning that you *change* or *re-set* something that is already there. It may be misleading in cases where the `unique_ptr` was previously empty. Moreover `reset()` solution has the benefit of being shorter, more explicit (you can see the "new")
- using assignment form `make_unique` conveys the meaning on a more abstract level: "make an unique `someObject` instance and place it here". Some people find that clearer and more precise, other people think it hides the actual allocation. Moreover, `make_unique` creates an temporary, which is moved into the target. The optimiser is allowed to elide that altogether.

### Exception Safety

Generally speaking, `make_unique` can change the exception safety in some situations. For this reason, it is often recommended to make a habit of using `make_unique`. In practice, this becomes relevant *if you create several unique-managed objects.*

```
someFunction(make_unique<someObject>(arg1),
             make_unique<someObject>(arg2));
```

If the ctor of one fails, the other one is always safely managed.

However, in the situation discussed here, we only create one object. So what happens in case of an exeption?

- If we use `reset(new someObject)`, the argument is created first. If this blows up, fine, the reset function is not called. BUT if `reset()` has to clean-up an existing other instance, and the *destructor* of that one throws, then we've got a problem: the `reset()` call will be left by exception, and the newly heap allocated argument leaks.
- on the other hand, if we assign from `make_unique()`, this special situation is handled safely: if the destructor of the old instance throws, stack unwinding will call the destructor of the temporary returned by `make_unique()`.

BUT this is a *mostly theoretical* argument. In practice, there is kind of a »social contract« to the end that decent people **do not throw on destruction**. And this stands for good reason: objects throwing on dtor call can cause endless pain and basically jeopardise the ability to handle any kind of "situation".

Comment: You *don't* want a raw call to `operator new` in your ctor-initializer-list.  Prefer to move-construct from the result of `make_unique`.

Comment: There is nothing inherently evil with an allocation by `new`. The smart-ptr protects against leaks.
@ben-voigt : roughly half of the preople just love abstractions, the other half loves to see the real thing. If you see the concept ("allocation") as the real thing or if you see the implementaton (`operator new`) as the real thing is a matter of attitude. You should not paint the one or the other as evil